# Extract the date and month in codeigniter

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, codeigniter-2

How extract the date and month in codeigniter

```
<?php echo $row->order_date; ?>
```

This code return the date in **YYYY-MM-DD** format .I want to change the format in to **MM-DD** in codeigniter view.

Comment: in `db` -> `sql query` or `php`?

Comment: in codeigniter view.(php)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [**DateTime**](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php) class

Try this way

```
$date = DateTime::createFromFormat('Y-m-d', $row->order_date);
$new_date_format = $date->format('m-d');
```

**PS**: suppose, the `order_date` is comming from db so i would recommand you to convert date in `sql` query.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
$date = $row->order_date;

echo date_format($date, 'm-d');
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$date_month = date('m-d',strtotime($row->order_date));
```

This is the very easiest way :)